# Why does Macklemore sing "If you're wondering, yes, I does my thing"?

Tags: lyrics

In the song *Brad Pitt's Cousin* Mr Macklemore says "If you're wondering, yes, I does my thing". Why <strike>he says</strike> does he say "I does"? And is that grammatically correct?

Comment: No, it is not grammatical, and there are other ungrammaticalities too. But it's a song, we don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an equivalent of "I do", found in various English dialects across America and around the world. The (grammatical) circumstances in which it can be used will differ between dialects and registers.

It may be adopted by speakers of other varieties of English for stylistic reasons, as is the case here. Almost every English native speaker has probably heard it (and similar nonstandard conjugation such as "is you or is you ain't my baby") at some point in their life.

It is not grammatically correct according to standard grammars of English.